# MSBuild not updating NuGet references when building with PackageVersion Property

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I've got two .NetStandard NuGet Packages that I'm building in the same solution (A and B)

A has a project reference to B.

By default, when I build in VS it will create me a NuGet package for both projects.

The package `A.1.0.0.nupkg` will contain this dependency, which was automatically added by msbuild:

```
<dependency id="B" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

That works fine, and its automatic which is great.

If I change the Package Version of B, to `2.0.0` and build, the line in `A.nuspec` will be automatically updated to:

```
<dependency id="B" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

This is fantastic, and it works like magic.

Problem is, this does **not** work if I build using the PackageVersion property:

```
msbuild /p:PackageVersion="3.0.0"
```

I would expect that msbuild would create two nupkgs:

- `A.3.0.0.nupkg`
- `B.3.0.0.nupkg`

And it does. However, `A.nuspec` still has this dependency:

```
<dependency id="B" version="2.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

I would expect it to be `version="3.0.0"`

Are there any workarounds for this? Is there a different way I should be configuring my packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (NuGet 4.5.0), the version is locked during the restore operation and not during the package build.

This will be changed in NuGet 4.6.0 (included in VS 15.6).

To work around this, use `msbuild /restore /p:PackageVersion=3.0.0` instead.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4337) for more details.

Comment: I assume this would run before the regular `msbuild` command that builds the project? The version of `msbuild` I have does not have the `/restore` flag. What version are you on?

Comment: 15.5 introduced the `/restore` flag which is a safe way to run the `Restore` and other targets in the same invocation and pass parameters to both

Comment: Just updated VS, and this seems to work well. For anyone reading in the future, I simply added the `/restore` flag to my `msbuild` invocation. I tested with VS/MSBuild 15.5.3